# Right justify numbers in a text output in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I am just starting in RoR and modifying an existing program.  Using Ruby 2.2.2p95, Rails 4.1.13.rc1 and Prawn 2.0.1
Text is in a bounded box.

```
pdf.column_box([0,pdf.cursor], :columns => 2, :width ==> pdf.bounds.width

person_text << "\n#{sprintf "%20d", count} #{'Grandchild'.pluralize(count)}"
```

If count = 234 then the output is:

```
234 Grandchildren
```

If count = 4238 then the output is:

```
4238 Grandchildren
```

There is no blank padding to right justify the numbers in a 20 space field.  Output should look as follows:

```
            234 Grandchildren
           4238 Grandchildren
```

What is wrong?
How can this be coded?

Comment: Issue is with Prawn.  Prawn strips white spaces both before and after.  Output is at left margin with leading blanks.

Answer (score 0):

String class has two methods called [ljust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) and [rjust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) that could help to you

```
2.2.2 :010 > str=123
 => 123 
2.2.2 :011 > "#{str.to_s.ljust(5)} Grandchildren"
 => "123   Grandchildren" 
2.2.2 :012 > str=1234
 => 1234 
2.2.2 :013 > "#{str.to_s.ljust(5)} Grandchildren"
 => "1234  Grandchildren" 
2.2.2 :014 > "#{"123".to_s.ljust(5)} Grandchildren"
 => "123   Grandchildren" 
2.2.2 :015 >
```

And if you are doing a webpage you could be able to do it via css too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This does not work with Prawn.  There are leading blanks with this solution that are stripped by Prawn.

Comment: Can you create a table with blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the white stripping in Prawn, put a nbsp in the first chr. pos.

```
 >   count = 4235
 >   srt = "#{sprintf("%20d", count)}"
 >   string = srt.gsub(/ (?= )/, Prawn::Text::NBSP)
 >   person_text << "\n#{string}  #{'Child'.pluralize(count)}"

   =>                 4235 Children
```